# how to add text view programatically in android with json

Tags: android

friends i want to create a app which have create text view from the JSON array
in example

```
"name":"Lenovo","price":"5000","description":"2 gb ram","type":"mobile"
```

it will be change it know the values and create a text field with this titles name ,type,price

Comment: Try parsing Json and using TextView.setText()

Comment: @Selva - provide full json

Comment: you need to iterate first the json string. then dynamically create TextView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..
Create a layout with LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</LinearLayout>
```

Then iterate your json

```
LinearLayout linearLayout= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);     
linearLayout.removeAllViews();                             

Iterator<String> iter = new JSONObject("JSON STRING").keys();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String key = iter.next();
    try {
        Object value = json.get(key);

        TextView textView= new TextView(this);              
        textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 48));
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);                       
        textView.setText(key+" : "+value.toString());                                    
        linearLayout.addView(textView);     


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // Something went wrong!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to consume your json somehow, use framework like `gson` or class like `JSONObject` (find on web if you need to).

Assume you have data to put in `TextView` so next you need to create your `TextView` in your activity:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this); //it need context
textView.setText(yourJSONObject.getText());
```

Last part is to put `TextView` to your layout, (in this case linearLayout).

```
yourLinearLayout.addView(addView(textVIew))
```